# How to Reset Chrome to Defaults using the Location bar //

Tags: google-chrome

You can [reset Chrome to original defaults via the menu](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en-GB) but it's a pretty complicated menu navigation.

I'm helping very non-technical folks and looking for simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this is possible without the user installing a plugin - so in the absense of other answers...

probably the easiest way you will be able to talk through the non-technical folks over the telephone is by giving them this series of keyboard commands:

- ALT-F
- Letter S
- Type "Reset Settings"
- Press Tab
- Press Space
- Press Tab Twice
- Press Space again

That is the keyboard-shortcut way of resetting to default.